# How to log system activity the whole day

Tags: macos, activity-monitor, monitoring

How can I log my Macs system activity the whole day (on OS X Mavericks)? E.g. memory and CPU usage?

**Update**

I tried [OsTrack](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/os-track-system-monitor/id448046667?mt=12), but it crashes all the time.

Comment: Are you looking for software recommendations or help creating a script+launchd job to gather this information?

Comment: If there is any possibility to log the activity without third party software, a script would be the best solution. But I never used AppleScript before, so I would need the whole script or a software recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

The average energy impact column in Activity Monitor shows the average energy (or CPU) use for the last 8 hours:

[image]

If you have downloaded Xcode, you might use the Activity Monitor template in Instruments:

[image]

With `top`, you can use `-a` for accumulative display. `-o cpu` orders processes by CPU use:

```
top -a -o cpu
```

To track the average CPU use of processes, run `EDITOR=nano crontab -e` and add a line like this:

```
* * * * * ps -eco '\%cpu= comm='|sed $'s/^ *//;s/ /\t/'>>~/Documents/cpu
```

Then run `awk -F$'\t' '{a[$2]+=$1}END{for(i in a)print a[i],i}' ~/Documents/cpu|sort -rn` later.